# Calls that precede a function's definition cannot be inlined?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, inlining

The [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) contains the following:

> When a function is both inline and static, if all calls to the
>   function are integrated into the caller, and the function's address is
>   never used, then the function's own assembler code is never
>   referenced. In this case, GCC does not actually output assembler code
>   for the function, unless you specify the option
>   -fkeep-inline-functions. Some calls cannot be integrated for various reasons (in particular, **calls that precede the function's definition
>   cannot be integrated**, and neither can recursive calls within the
>   definition).

That always sounded absurd to me -- why would a modern compiler be that dumb? After a quick test it does seem untrue.

The test code:

```
static inline int foo();

int bar() {
    return foo();
}

int foo() {
    return 42;
}
```

The result with gcc-4.9.2 on Linux contains code for `bar()` but none for `foo()`. You can see that `foo()` has been integrated:

```
bar:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $42, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

If I compile as C++ the result is the same, except for name mangling.

Contrary to the documentation, despite `foo()` being defined after the call in `bar()`, `foo()` has been completely integrated into `bar()`.

Do I misunderstand the documentation or is it incorrect? Perhaps it's correct for some more complicated case?

I don't know if there's a technical distinction between "integrate" and "inline" but I suspect "integrate" is being used to distinguish from keyword `inline` and it just refers to function inlining (hence the title).

This question is tagged as C and C++ because this portion of the gcc documentation pertains to the "C language family" and I expect the answer to be the same for the two languages.

Comment: That sentence is already present in gcc 3.0.4 documentation.  They probably enhanced the compiler without modifying the documentation.

Comment: Yeah. It seems it does not correspond to what actually happens. Though, I have tried it also on 4.8.1 - the same behaviour.

Comment: It's even in gcc 2.95.3 documentation.

Comment: @AProgrammer: That sounds plausible. I tried the example shown here with gcc 3.0 and it didn't get inlined, but did after I moved the definition of `foo` to the top.

Comment: @AProgrammer I would note that, for GCC, a lot of the documentation I've seen - and especially that which they've left prominently available via Google - is outdated. There's really no substitute for testing it oneself. I kinda wish it weren't so, but hey, it encourages users to get hands-on, so silver lining? +1 to the OP for testing it themselves. Anyway, of course, nowadays `-flto` is a thing, so all traditional ideas about inlining are moot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gcc used to compile and optimize one function at a time, as soon as they were parsed, before parsing the next one.  IIRC, it is only in the 4.X time frame that they introduced the `-funit-at-a-time` option which postponed the optimization to after having read the whole compilation unit and then they waited some releases to enable it by default.

The possibility of inlining function defined after the call has probably be introduced as part of the `-funit-at-a-time` work, and the documentation of inline (the mention about calls preceding the definition dates back at least to 2.95) has not updated then.